# Is Miss Monochrome's voice computer edited?

Tags: anime-production, miss-monochrome

In the Miss Monochrome anime series, Miss Monochrome is depicted as an android and thus talks like a robot. Is this computer edited or does Horie Yui actually speak like that?

Comment: Horie Yui is talented, for sure, but I don't think even she has the capability to make her voice sound _that_ auto-tuned.

Answer (score 2):

Basically everything I've found indicates that she's autotuned, including [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MissMonochrome) and [THEM Anime Reviews](https://www.themanime.org/viewreview.php?id=1660). You can hear Horie Yui speaking normally [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njwsHBZu4oE) and Miss Monochrome's autotuned singing [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TnsqwvsiMM). It's possible to hear some of the autotuning behind her singing.